# String comparison for constant string and a string element in C++ using strcmp

Tags: c++, string, char, strcmp

I am trying to convert `III` stored in string `s` in Roman numerals to 3. Here is a code snippet:

```cpp
int i = 0;
int num = 0;
while (i < s.size()){
    if (strcmp(s[i], "I") == 0){
        num = num + 1;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    else{
        continue;
    }
}

return num;
```

I am facing issues with using the `strcmp()` function. How can I use it successfully?

Here is the error:

```
Line 18: Char 17: error: no matching function for call to 'strcmp'
            if (strcmp(s[i], "I") == 0){
                ^~~~~~
/usr/include/string.h:137:12: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion 
from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, 
char>::value_type' (aka 'char') to 'const char *' for 1st argument; 
take the address of the argument with &
extern int strcmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2)
           ^
```

Comment: Usage of `s.size()` indicates this is not `C`.  Tag the language that you're using.  Also as an aside, this: `IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII` is not a valid Roman numeral, but your program will process it as if it is one.

Comment: `s[i] == 'I'` ... you're comparing characters, not c strings.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `s[i]` of type `char`(not a string) with `"I"` of type `const char*`(is string).

In this case, you just need to compare `s[i] == 'I'`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `s.size()`, it seems `s` is `std::string` and `s[i]` would be a character at index i. It's not a `char*` so obviously you can't compare that with `"I"` which is a `const char[2]`. To compare characters you do that directly: `s[i] == 'I'`

If you really want to do a string compare then you must get a `const char*` from `s`:

```
if (strncmp(s.c_str() + i, "I", 1) == 0){
```